# How to export MySQL database under the .db extension

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to export the **MySQL** database under the **.db** extension?  If it is possible how to do it?

Comment: Simply specify the dump filename with needed extension.

Comment: The `.db` file extension often is used for a [SQLite database](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html).  If that's what you want you will need to convert your data to that format.  Please [edit] your question to be specific about what you want.